# Sonar Plugin configuration to use cobertura

Tags: maven, sonarqube, cobertura

Please let me know how to configure sonar to use cobertura instead of jacoco which is the default. 
i have this in my parent pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 </plugin>
```

Apart from this i dont know how to add configuration properties.Cobertura setting is there in child poms which will build n show coverage with cobertura locally.
I problem is configuring the right setting in parent pom.and what are the changes i should make in the sonar web interface ->General Settings.

Help Appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) about the properties.  I suspect you want to redefine the `sonar.java.coveragePlugin` property as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to configure that in Sonar directly. Besides, in order to use Cobertura for Java 7 projects you need Cobertura >= 2.0 which was only released a few days ago.

As a sidenote, here a two somewhat older comparisons of the various coverage tools for Sonar:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-tools-comparison
- http://www.sonarsource.org/pick-your-code-coverage-tool-in-sonar-2-2/